# Python Bottle - Difference between "redirect" and "return template"

Tags: python, redirect, bottle

I have two questions regarding Bottle:

1) What is the difference between:

`redirect('/login')` and `return template('login')`

Wouldn't both make the user go on same the `/login` page?

2) Can I pass arguments to `redirect` as I do in case of `return`?

For e.g.:

Does this work: `redirect('/login', userName="foo")` as we do in this case:

`return template('login', userName="foo")`

Comment: Not familiar with Bottle but in Flask `return template` (`render_template` to be mroe precise) will render a template and `redirect` will send the user to a different view function and then you will get whatever returns form that function, a different template, some JSON or god help you XML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1) What is the difference between:
>
> `redirect('/login')` and `return template('login')`

From the [bottle documentation for redirect](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-errors-and-redirects):

> To redirect a client to a different URL, you can send a `303 See Other`
>   response with the `Location` header set to the new URL. **redirect()** does
>   that for you

The `redirect()` method will send a 303 response to the user, who will then send another request to your server for the '/login' page. If you use the `template()` method, you will be returning the web page directly to the user.

> 2) Can I pass arguments to `redirect` as I do in case of `return`?

`redirect()` does not accept query variables, such as those you pass to `template()`. If you want to use those variables, you will need to set them explicitly on the url. E.g. to use a url `'/login'` with `userName="foo"`, you need to call `redirect('/login?userName="foo")`

**Edit** if you don't want to store all of the variables in the url, you should try to get those values when the page is rendered.
e.g. Call `redirect('/login')` without the variables and make it the responsibility of the method that renders '/login' to call `template()` with the correct variables.

Comment: 1) Few things I observed - if I `return`, it simply returns the template to the user. But if I `redirect`, the control goes to that route, its function is executed and then the template is returned to the user. Also, in `redirect`, the url changes to the redirected route name whereas in case of `return template`, the url does not change.


2)Normally, I include in the tpl file something like this: `<b>Hellp {{userName}}</b>`. So that results in - **`Hello foo`**. If I pass variables from url as you mentioned, can I use them inside the tpl as well as?

Comment: @ss2025 2) I think so, but you can always try to use redirect with you page to see if it works.

Comment: Yeah thanks! This thing works.. but is there a way other than putting it in the url? Coz there are lot of such variables and I dont want to make the url  look complicated..

Comment: You could use a POST request instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087796/redirecting-to-a-url-with-post-data-using-python-bottle